# How to convert integration from $\mathbb C$ to $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb T$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

By the change of variable ($z=re^{i\theta}$,  $z\in \mathbb C, \theta \in [0, 2\pi), r=|z|$), we may rewrite

$\int_{\mathbb C} e^{-|z|^2}\bar{z} \left(1+\left| \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2} \right|^2 \right)^p dz = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} re^{-i\theta} \left(1+|r\cos \theta|^2 \right)^p d\theta dr$

Heuristically, notice that  if $z=x+iy,$ then $z+ \bar{z}=2x$ and so $ \left(1+\left| \frac{z+
 \bar{z}}{2} \right|^2 \right)^p = (1+r^2)^p$. In view of this my question is:

> Can  we say
>
> $\int_{\mathbb C} e^{-|z|^2}\bar{z} \left(1+\left| \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2} \right|^2 \right)^p dz = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} re^{-i\theta} \left(1+r^2 \right)^p d\theta dr$?
>
> Or am I making some mistake?

Comment: I don't think $\mathop{dz}$ makes sense, it is reserved for contour integral, and here you work on a surface. The problem is not the polar transformation, but the initial definition of LHS.

Comment: What is the T in the title?

Comment: That's circle group. $[0,2\pi)=\mathbb T$ (measure theoretically )

Answer (score 1):

You should have $(1+|x|^{2})^{p}=(1+r^{2}\cos^{2} \, \theta)^{p}$ instead of $(1+r^{2})^{p}$.